# SELECT in MySQL not functioning

Tags: mysql, node.js

At one point I was trying to use MySQL for my Nodejs project. No matter what I did it wouldn't perform the SELECT operation correctly or would bug out and not work. I have since tried using FS but I realized the overhead is going to be too much and Firestore is going to be far too complicated.
Here is a quick snip of my code - it crashes saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined" (flag is in the database, ID and Flag are both fields in the database)

Am I misusing this and how can I fix it? (I might end up needing more help with debugging if it continues to not write to the database or read from it properly)

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM pedodb WHERE ID = ?`, [msg.author.id],
function (err, result, fields) {
//callback(null, rows, fields);
console.log("Query Initiated")
if (ageCheck(msg.content.toLowerCase(), "8", "15")) {
    if (result.flag in {
            1: "P",
            2: "S",
            3: "YA",
            4: "A"
        }) {

        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check `if (err) { console.log(err); return; }` as a first line in your callback function. Could be the table doesn't exist.

Also, result is an array, so, you should check if `result.length > 0` and use `result[0].flag`, should such column exist in the table.

Comment: I used result.length > 0 in a IF statement and it returned "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and result returns undefined when I log it.

Is this because Javascript is asynchronous? How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Did you check for err being null? No, it is not because JS is asynchronous. It is because if err is not null (i.e. there was an error in your statement), then result is null

Comment: After a long session of debugging it still does not behave the way it should. console.log(err); returns null in console as does result (result returns [] specifically)  yet I know there should be an entry in the database. What could be wrong with my statement? Could it be because ID is nothing but a number (could it be attempting to simplify?)

How would I go about fixing this, my debugging has turned up resultless

Comment: I am not sure I understand, how can it be, that there is an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when also, result returns "[]" (i.e. empty array, which means result is defined and has at least the 'length' property). I would try putting the id inside the query, without question mark, to debug. Also run the same string in mysql client, to make sure.

Comment: `
[]
 ---- DEBUG INFORMATION ----
null
Query Initiated
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined
`
That is my error.

The [] is the result from MySQL. null is the error, so there shouldn't be one. I know the value is in the database because I set it up specifically to show, so I am guessing it must be an error in my MySQL statement because there is no way it isn't in the database. I ended up removing result.length when I was debugging, for reference, now it's trying to read from a field, Flag.