# MySQL Result is undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

This code is supposed to execute and compare flags on an ID. It throws an error  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` and when I put a console.log in there to see what result is, it returned undefined even though it should return from the MySQL Query. MySQL is set up properly and the table exists.
Is this because Javascript is asynchronous? How do I fix this?

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM pedodb WHERE ID = ?`, [ID],
            function (err, result, fields) {
                if (result.length > "0") {
            if (result[0].flag == "P") {
                console.log("This isn't logged")
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you double check your `ID` is correct?

Comment: It's likely the same problem as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974816/select-in-mysql-not-functioning) where you've already been told to check for errors of the query...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can explain your observations is that either the result set is empty, or maybe an error happened during the query.  To check for this, you could use:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM pedodb WHERE ID = ?", [ID],
    function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err || !result || result.length == 0) {
            // handle error or empty result set here
            console.log("Something went wrong");
        }
        else if (result[0].flag == "P") {
            console.log("This isn't logged")
        }
    }
);
```